# jquery / javascript: jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

Tags: javascript, jquery

This little jQuery plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
```

How does it work? Where is the object binding - Array prototype to reverse function?
I don't really understand how it works behind the scene. Some explanation would be nice. Greetings

Comment: Originally, comes from [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@jquery.com/msg04261.html), and is termed by the author, Michael Geary, as "the world's shortest plugin". Apparently other Array methods can be applied in the same way: eg. `.sort()`, `.push()`, `.pop()`, `.unshift()` and `.shift()`. Presumably `.slice()` and `.splice()` too. I'm not so sure `.join()` would return a sensible result from a jQuery object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jQuery.fn` is an alias for `jQuery.prototype`.

So this plugin adds Array's `reverse` function to all objects created with `new JQuery()`, which is the case for the collections built with `$`.

And it works because the `reverse` function's [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.8) makes it apply to any object which has a length and indexed properties . You can test it using this :

```
var a = {0:'a', 1:'b'};
a.length = 2;
console.log([].reverse.call(a)); // it works
```

Comment: This behavior is [by design](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.8) and isn't going to change.

Answer (score 13):

`[].reverse` is the `.reverse()` function from *Array* prototype. jQuery is leveraging this instead of defining their own.

`[]` creates an empty *Array* and it's perfectly valid to reference the `.reverse` function from it.

So now, in jQuery, one can do `$.reverse()` if the jQuery object contains a collection of elements.

Comment: Exactly. And it works because jQuery mimics the structure of an array. +1!